# Issue when running mule maven project

Tags: maven, mule

I am trying to run my project using maven to package into WAR file' but I am getting this error `Unable to copy project zip file to the embedded Mule instance. Project: [Mule Project] Name: test - Domain: default Source '/home/AnypointStudio/workspace/test/target/test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip' does not exist`, How to fix?

Comment: Hi can you post any part of your pom.xml or provide info about the specific Mule Version of IDE you are using? Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817728/anypoint-studio-fails-when-running-maven-project/33945656)   or [here](http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/1010/mule-esb-ce-fails-to-deploy-maven-project-if-pom-xml-contains.html) for similar issues

Comment: yes, I have seen the links you have provided, but no luck! my version of anypoint studio is: 5.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studio's Maven plugin doesn't support WAR format as output. Try with command line Maven or m2e Eclipse plugin.

Comment: If you are compiling as a WAR then you need to deploy to a Java web container. There are several plugins and tutorials you should be able to find in the Internet for that but keep in mind that Studio won't support anything of that directly.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue. Check the target directory and see if an output file is generated(i.e jar, war, etc.) If a file is there then the output file is being generated properly. Open the pom.xml file for the project and change the element inside the packaging tag of the project to mule.

i.e `<packaging>jar</packaging> --> <packaging>mule</packaging>`